# MSHYBRID boot on UEFI mode

Tags: uefi, nvidia-optimus, gpu

I have a Clevo P65xRP notebook with a intel onboard GPU and a GTX1060 discrete GPU. After months trying to make work on UEFI and no luck with several kinds of distro's(ubuntu and all it's flavours, 16.04, 16.10, several kernels, FEDORA 23, 24, 25, mandriva, Solus, elementary OS, debian and others) I managed to do so. On UEFI with secure boot disabled(but also works with secure boot enabled) and Windows 10 fast boot option disabled:

There is no need for nomodeset or i915.modeset=1 or nouveau.modeset=1. On the GRUB2 boot screen just press "e" and change the option "SET GFXPAYLOAD = keep" to "SET GFXPAYLOAD = text". If there is no such option add just before the "linux = ...." line. If a gfxmode option is present, just change to "SET GFXPAYLOAD = text".

After months trying I did not find anywhere this information, so I am just telling noobs like me how to do this. Bad luck for is that my touchpad is Synaptics and works 1 out of 10 boots on UEFI.

Comment: I would suggest changing this into a proper question like "How for I install Linux on a Clevo P65xRP Laptop?", with a brief explanation about what you're trying to answer, and then take what you've written above to create a proper answer to it.  That way, it's less like a forum post, and fits better with the AskUbuntu style of Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me.

To get the trackpad working I used `i8042.reset` just before `quiet splash`.